# How to disable previous time when chosen date is today?

Tags: vue.js, time, vuejs3, timepicker

I'm having these two datepicker and timepicker.

```
<b-form-datepicker v-model="notification_date"></b-form-datepicker>
<b-form-timepicker v-model="notification_hour"></b-form-timepicker>
```

If the date the user chose is today, for example, 14/06/2023, when the user choose the time in the timepicker, I want to disable all of the previous time, for example, if now is 2:00 pm, then the user can't choose 1:00 pm, or 1:59 pm, etc.

I have tried and search the document for the b-form-timepicker but there isn't any properties that can help me in this problem, any suggestion?